# Is there a word for "outsourcing work to an internal employee/person"?

Tags: single-word-requests

A company wouldn't say they, "outsourced their advertising to Jim", who is an employee of the company because that just doesn't sound right. What is a word similar to "outsource" in a situation like so?

Comment: I have heard the term **insourcing** used when a previously outsourced function was brought back in house.

Comment: Normally the internal work is *assigned* to an employee.

Comment: It's unclear what concept you're trying to find a term for. It would help to provide some examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps

> The company **assigned** advertising to Jim.

[Assign](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/assign): (2) to give out or announce as a task:
*to assign homework*.

If Jim is already employed by the company, then you are correct that the assign would not properly be called *outsourcing*.

Comment: *Assign* is good.  you can also *delegate*.